# How can I add tooltip on world map svg

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip

I have a SVG of all countries in the world and I want to add a tooltip on whenever you hover over a country that is already highlighted blue above the country. That tooltip will contain a list of names. How can I achieve this?

What I am looking for is demonstrated here, just hover over the text "Top" at the top of the page here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

This is the SVG Map: http://occ.uk.com/occ/associate-members/

This is the code for the map: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofm2io1ahv2k7gh/SVGWorldMapSharing.html?dl=0

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this is more a job to be done than a question

Comment: Yes it does sound like that actually, sorry about that. Can you please direct me to the right direction? Where would I add the HTML for the tooltip for each country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is available on
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdjJzz

Add the onmouseevent handler below to your svg element; i.e. handleMouseMove="onmousemove(event)"

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
  var countryId = event.target.id;
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

  switch (countryId) {
    case "AT":
    case "FR":
    case "DE":
    case "IT":
    case "NL":
    case "AU":
    case "IL":
      break;
    default:
      return tooltip.classList.remove("active");
  }

  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  tooltip.style.left = (x + 20) + "px";
  tooltip.style.top = (y - 20) + "px";
  tooltip.innerHTML = countryId;
  tooltip.classList.add("active");

}
```

Use the following css

```
.tooltiptext {
  display: none;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltiptext.active {
  display: initial;
}
```

Add the following element to your html, just before the svg element. You may control the tooltip content based on your work, and you can do that dynamically by changing the inner html manually on mouse over.

```
<span class="tooltiptext" id="tooltip">Tooltip text</span>
```

Comment: This is a very good way of doing it, but I am getting an error every time I move the cursor on the SVG. The error is:

testingMap.html:62 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SVGSVGElement.onmousemove (testingMap.html:62)

Comment: Did you add <span class="tooltiptext" id="tooltip">Tooltip text</span>?

Comment: Yes, just above the svg element start

Comment: We should use a right event name; for instance handleMouseMove. I made the required change in my comment as well as the fiddle link

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, you are a legend.